# Unable to access Angular2 Route parameters with special characters

Tags: angular, jwt, angular2-routing

This is my component where i am accessing route params of route `list/hg76hjb.hhuh67.878hhuu`

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular2/router';

export class FooComponent {
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe((params:any) => {
     this.token = +params['token'];
    });
  }

}
```

this is my `app-routing.module.ts`

```
{path: 'list/:token', component: FooComponent}
```

`list/gfhg76.ghfhg6`- error which I am getting `Cannot GET list/gfhg76.ghfhg6`

`list/hgjjhk` - this.token is getting proper value i.e `hgjjhk`

Please help me to fetch this whole token `gfhg76.ghfhg6`

Comment: Special characters shouldn't be the problem here, as I tested this with the `hg76hjb.hhuh67.878hhuu` in my answer I provided below, and it worked correctly. You need to provide more code, e.g the the routing to your `FooComponent`, how you get your token etc, i.e meaning all relevant code to your problem.

Comment: and I suppose you have in your code `FooComponent implements OnInit` as well, now that you updated your questions. But just as a detail to perhaps add in your question, so that people won't react to that ;) Best would be if you could provide a plunker to recreate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to pass it like a string (if it's not) before navigating? Depends of course how your app is built.